# JSON data not loading with $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm trying to load JSON data into jQuery using `$.getJSON`. However, the alert I call does not show up (though I know the js is linked properly because other alerts outside the `$.getJSON` show up). I also know the `"test.json"` file is in the correct directory.

I've boiled it down to the simplest possible code to best find the answer to what I'm doing wrong:

The getjson.js file (inside a document ready):

```
$.getJSON("test.json", function(json) {
    alert("JSON Data: " + json.statename);
});
```

The JSON data in test.json is simply:

```
 {"statename": "Hawaii"}
```

And yet no alert shows up when the getjson.js file is loaded! In Firebug I see no request being sent either. I've Google'd around about this, but it looks to me like my syntax is ok, and I'm a newbie at JSON and jQuery so I just can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks a lot for any input here, going completely crazy with this!

Comment: Are you loading the file through a web server or directly from the file system? Ajax won't work if you do the latter. Watch the console for any messages.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Very new at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide correct `url` to `.getJSON` call. It won't work for local files on your computer.

Comment: Wow thanks, I feel dumb for not realizing that you have to include the whole path from the domain, not just from the local file. Glad it was a quick fix!